# Debugging custom targets in CLion

Tags: clion

I am able to debug executables in CLion using the debugger.
I want however to debug the executable with specific cmd line args and i want these arguments to appear in the CMake file.
I tried using

```
add_custom_target(run_my_exec
        COMMAND ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/my_exec ${MY_RUN_FLAGS}
        DEPENDS my_exec)
```

but when i try to debug it the breakpoints never hit.
Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can edit program argument through Run/Debug configurations dialog as described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html) and also [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/run-debug-configurations-dialog.html). The most simple way to get there is "Edit Configurations" as shown on the screenshot below:

[image: Edit Configurations...]

Then you can edit the target you want to debug (or duplicate it and edit the copy):

[image]

Comment: But these configurations are saved in CLion and not in the CMake file as i want.

Comment: @zbut Ah, I see. I'm afraid, the feature you're looking for isn't implemented in CLion. Please feel free to open a new request in our issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP